Как в Visual Studio Code настроить подцветку синтаксиса(js, vue), когда много кода
В общем, не знаю как правильно озаглавить проблему, но суть в том, что когда у меня написано мало кода, то подцветка адекватная и каждый компонент при клике через контрл редиректит в файл

Однако когда в коде в атрибуте тега слишком много кода, то подцветка теряется и весь код становится одноцветным. Как это называется и какой настройкой можно это исправить?


Уточнение - так происходит, когда внутри атрибута есть массив

Попробуйте убрать ненужную запятую после Объекта в Filters

Не помогает это

У вас само название компонента Autocomplete расцвечено разным - точно его неправильно "читает"  - закрывающий - /> красный? Ваш lead.origin есть? и он точно строковый? и т.д. -проверьте правильность всех переменных и уберите конечно ненужные запятые в массивах.

Это точно, правильно. Когда я убираю массив, всё становится нормально. В том и дело, что это редактор показывает неккоректно при массива

Возможно, что для Редактора слово Autocomplete - зарезервированное слово. Если не лениво - можете назвать другим Точно собственным именем и посмотреть)))
